# Understanding Python Script class usaged, when class is called in square braces

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am quite new to serious python Object oriented programing. I have a problem in understanding few command lines in python especially using pyQt5 module. Most of the script I am able to understand using online materials and blogs for python.

But, I am unable understand the below line of code clearly How it is woking and what exactly it is doing.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QComboBox, QToolBar, QAction,
.
.
class ActionActivationToolbar
  def __init__(self, parent = None, Action_controls_widget = None):
.
.
    **self.actuaterActivated[QAction].connect(toggle_snap)**
```

It would be nice if someone can provide me a link to understan such usage of classes (in Bold).

Comment: This connects a signal (`self.actuaterActivated` in this case) to a slot (`toggle_snap`). The `[QAction]` part is to indicate which signature should be used in case of overloaded signals.

Comment: That syntax is an indexing, like indexing a list or dictionary. Depending on what kind of object you get from `self.actuaterActivated`, different kinds of objects might be allowed as indexes. Dictionaries, for instance, allow any hashable objects to be keys, and class objects are hashable. I don't know enough about the specific QT types you're using to tell you what you're dealing with here, but it seems like passing it a class is an expected thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```
self.actuaterActivated[QAction].connect(toggle_snap)
```

connects a signal (`self.actuaterActivated`) to a slot (`toggle_snap`). The `[QAction]` part is to indicate which signature should be used in case of overloaded signals.

Here is a small example to illustrate this:

```
import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    combo.addItems(['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'banana'])
    combo.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(lambda x: print(f'the current text is {x}'))
    combo.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(lambda x: print(f'the currenct index is {x}'))
    combo.show()
    app.exec()
```

`QComboBox` has an overloaded signal `currentIndexChanged` which is sent when a new item is selected from the drop down list. This signal emits either a string (the text of the new current item), or an int (the index of the new current item in the list of items). `[int]` and `[str]` are used to distinguish to which version of the signal the slots should be connected. Without indicating a type, the default signature is used which is `(int)` in this case.

Comment: @ Heike Its very explanatory thank you very much. last doubt I want to get clear. how is the function connect is called(from where?) It is not present in QtWidgets. I had same quetion in my scrit. I found it is present in sqlite3 library but I call it no where

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking. `connect`  is a method of a `pyqtSignal`  object, not of a widget. You call it yourself if you want to connect a slot to a signal. Once a slot is connected to a signal it will be run automatically when the signal is emitted. The handling of slots and signals is managed by the Qt meta object system (see for example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#details).

Comment: Exactly for this explanation I was looking for Heike. Thanks a lot.